# How to add Matching Modes in Sphinxql query builder

Tags: php, laravel, sphinx, sphinxql, search-server

here is my query Sphinxql query

```
$query =SphinxQL::query()->select('*')
    ->from('table1')->match('title','hel',)->execute();

  //title is  column name
```

I need a records having the text `hel` anywhere `for eg mysql Like %string%`

In above its retrieving the records which are matching the `hel` words

I need to add `setmatchmode(SPH_MATCH_ANY)` where I need to add this is `Sphinxql` query

Answer (score 3):

Frankly you are better NOT using matching modes, even thou it is technically possible via SphinxQL.

Instead just rewrite the query using quorum syntax....

```
->match('title',expr('"hel two there"/1'))
```

Edited to clarify may need to use an expression to avoid automatic escaping provided by the framework. (thanks to the comments!)

Comment: You might need to wrap the match in an expression, otherwise the control characters will be escaped. The Laravel library uses Foolz\SphinxQL (disclaimer: I am the creator). `->match('title', \Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL::expr('"hel two there"/1'))`. Read further on match(): https://github.com/FoolCode/SphinxQL-Query-Builder#match